# Как правильно подключить js-скрипт внутрь шаблона компонента bitrix

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

На работе поставили задачу внедрить внутри формы функцию автозаполнения для одного из инпутов. Форма представляет из себя компонент битрикса. я создал тестовую страничку, где добавил обычный инпут, скрипт работает корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при переносе скрипта на страницу с формой, автозаполнение уже не отрабатывает. В консоли получаю следующую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код скрипта:

```
`\Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::getInstance()->addJs('https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js');
    \Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::getInstance()->addString('<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("/bitrix/admin/regions.txt", function(data) {
    var regions = data.replace(/\r\n/g,\'\n\').split(\'\n\');
    console.log(regions);
    $("#regions").autocomplete({
    source: regions,
    minLength: 2,
    });
    });
    });
    </script>', false, \Bitrix\Main\Page\AssetLocation::AFTER_JS);`
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело? как мне корректно добавить js-код внутрь этой формы?
Заранее спасибо всем!

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Что за компонент формы вы используете? Какой-то стандартный или самописный? В коде компонента идет где-нибудь подключение того же jquery-ui? Причем подключение не обязательно в шаблоне компоненты может быть. Тем же инспектором хрома можно посмотреть какие файлы и откуда подключаются.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, может быть конфликт в jquery-ui. Страница с формой может уже сама подтягивать jquery-ui из ядра, а вы загружаете ещё экземпляр.

Во-вторых, скрипт корректнее было бы поместить в файл script.js шаблона компонента. Скопируйте шаблон компонента в свой шаблон сайта и правьте его.